# How to handle snmp traps failures

Tags: java, snmp

I am continuously monitoring a process by using pgrep command and sending traps to another machine by using snmp4j.

This is my code to monitor the process:

```
String[] process = new String[] {"/bin/sh", "-c","pgrep httpd" };
Process proc = new ProcessBuilder(process).start();
InputStreamReader input = new InputStreamReader(proc.getInputStream());
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(input);
String line = reader.readLine();
int rc = proc.waitFor();
reader.close();
input.close();
```

I am limiting the number of traps sent to the machine with iptables but whenever the trap count increases above the configured count, I get the following error:

```
org.snmp4j.MessageException: Operation not permitted
        at org.snmp4j.MessageDispatcherImpl.sendPdu(Unknown Source)
        at org.snmp4j.Snmp.sendMessage(Unknown Source)
        at org.snmp4j.Snmp.send(Unknown Source)
        at org.snmp4j.Snmp.send(Unknown Source)
```

When I get this error /proc/(pid)/fd count also increases in the machine then reaches the maximum fd count and I get theese error messages:

- "MESSAGE: Too many open files
  java.net.SocketException: Too many
  open files"
- Cannot run program "/bin/sh":
  java.io.IOException: error=24, Too
  many open files.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: The last error can be resolved by increasing the open file count. For linux: http://serverfault.com/questions/20387/debian-too-many-open-files. Which files are opened so much? Can you report this information? You can get it via lsof. Maybe snmp4j doesn't handle the error condition very well.

Comment: It sounds like you have a file descriptor leak somewhere.  As dmeister suggested, you can use lsof to see which files are open (and left open) and sockstat to see which sockets are open.